# Can geopy return geocoding quality? (using Bing API)

Tags: bing, bing-api, geopy, geocoder

I've been reading the [docs](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html?highlight=bing#geopy.geocoders.Bing.geocode) for the Bing geocoder using geopy and there doesn't seem to be a parameter for geocoding quality as an output.

In particular, I'm looking for 'matchCodes' and 'confidence' as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/locations/location-data).

Anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Location.raw`](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.location.Location) attribute contains the raw geocoding response, from which these params can be retrieved:

```
In [1]: import os
   ...: from geopy.geocoders import Bing

In [2]: g = Bing(api_key=os.environ['BING_KEY'])
   ...: l = g.geocode("moscow")

In [3]: l.raw
Out[3]:
{'__type': 'Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1',
 'bbox': [55.493934631347656,
  37.31906509399414,
  55.9488410949707,
  37.94414520263672],
 'name': 'Moscow City',
 'point': {'type': 'Point',
  'coordinates': [55.55002975463867, 37.36982727050781]},
 'address': {'adminDistrict': 'Moscow City',
  'countryRegion': 'Russia',
  'formattedAddress': 'Moscow City'},
 'confidence': 'High',
 'entityType': 'AdminDivision1',
 'geocodePoints': [{'type': 'Point',
   'coordinates': [55.55002975463867, 37.36982727050781],
   'calculationMethod': 'Rooftop',
   'usageTypes': ['Display']}],
 'matchCodes': ['Ambiguous']}

In [4]: l.raw['confidence']
Out[4]: 'High'

In [5]: l.raw['matchCodes']
Out[5]: ['Ambiguous']
```